# Ударение в слове "гофрированный"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: гоф**ри**рованный или гофри**ро**ванный (второй вариант услышала по ТВ) — ведь изначальное слово — гоф**ре**.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: гофри**ро**ванный.

Орфоэпический словарь русского языка: http://orfoslova.dljatebja.ru/Slovar%27/g/30150.html

гофрирОванный http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/gofrirovanniy/?q=532&n=26198

Comment: А где по ссылке слово *гофрированный*?

Comment: ГофрирОванный - по второй ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно нормам литературного произношения, корректный вариант — гофрир**о**ванный.

Страдательное причастие *гофрир**о**ванный* образовано от глагола *гофриров**а**ть* (ср. также *бал**о**ванный* от *балов**а**ть*, *брак**о**ванный* от *браков**а**ть*).

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, гофрир**о**ванный.
Тут не единичная словарная норма, тут вполне четкая тенденция делать удорным О в сложном суффиксе "-ированн(ый)". Глазурованный, лакированный, форированный...
примеров обратного я что-то и не вспомню. Разве что куп**и**рованный, но это тоже весьма своеобразное слово, по форме - причастие, а фактически образовано не от "купе". Вариант гофр**и**ровннай был бы таким же неожиданным  исключением.

Answer (score 0):

**Правильно: гофрировАть, гофрирОванный:**

Я — здесь, но с удочкой моя рука, Где льёт просолнеченная река Коричневатую свою волну По гофрирОванному ею дну (И. Северянин).

Но вот из словаря Резниченко: **Неудивительно, если вы произносите это слово по-другому.** Норма ударения   в нем колеблется давно, и в старинных словарях можно встретить "гофрИровать". Вот и словарь Аванесова (1987 г.) предупреждает: не рек. гофрИрованный.